# How to put Firebase invite builder inside an android activity?

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, android-activity, firebase-invites

I want to build an android app using Firebase invites so that users can start inviting their friends after starting the app. The issue is the firebase invite opens up as a separate activity without even  a toolbar , it does not look like the part of the app . So , i Want to include it in an activity . As per the code given in documentation , it uses startActivityForResult to start the new Intent which is only a IntentBuilder . How do i customize it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked. Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

To start invitation you call `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);` and you cant embed it in your activity. See [best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/best-practices) there is Customize your invitations section